# Import 3D tracking data in ECEF coordinates from a Google Earth Studio project as a layer of of points into a WGS 84 QGIS project

Tags: qgis, ecef

In addition to the rendered frames, Google Earth Studio has the option to generate a .jsx or a .json file with the 3D tracking information. (for information see https://earth.google.com/studio/docs/advanced-features/3d-camera-export/ ).
The JSON file has the camera position for each frame in xyz Global coordinates per ECEF (Earth Centered, Earth Fixed)) as well as lat long altitude coordinates. I want to use this information to produce the rendered frames as atlas pages in QGIS.

After converting the JSON to a CSV, I can create a layer from it in QGIS but the locations on the map are nowhere where there should be. I have experimented with different CRS for the layer but none seem to position the positions correctly on the map.

Answer (score 1):

The question remains how to create a layer in QGIS from a CSV file with  xyz or lat long point ECEF coordinates, but I found a workaround for the problem. I converted the CSV file with lat long altitude coordinates into a GeoJSON, create a layer in QGIS from that GeoJSON that can be used to produce atlas pages in QGIS.

In short: if you want to use Google earth studio to create video animations in Adobe After Effects, you can substitute the standard google earth footage by any Geo footage from QGIS by exporting the google earth studio JSON, convert it into a CSV format, convert it into a GeoJSON, use that to produce atlas frames to replace the google earth footage in Adobe After Effects.